# Degeneration of relative Hodge-de Rham spectral sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, spectral-sequences

$$\require{AMScd}$$
$$\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Hdr}{H_{\mathrm{dRh}}}
\newcommand{\tensor}{\otimes}
\newcommand{\Ohol}{\mathcal{O}}$$

Please excuse that this rather long question is essentially of the type "proof verification" which, I know, is frowned upon at this site. But I have no possibility to ask anyone in this case personally and by studying literature from the internet could not come to a final conclusion by myself.

Let $f: X \to S$ be a smooth projective map of smooth varieties over $\CC$,
with $S/k$ a one-dimensional smooth affine curve over $\CC$.

Because of the Hodge-Decomposition for each $s \in S$, closed point, we have

$$
\Hdr^r(X_s / s) =  \bigoplus_{p+q = r} H^q(X_s, \Omega_{X_s|k(s)}^p) = 
\bigoplus_{p+q = r} H^q(X, \Omega_{X|S}^p \tensor k(s))
$$

Now all $X_s \cong X_{s'}$ are isomorphic as complex manifolds, because 
$f:X \to S$ is a proper submersion and so by the Ehresmann fibration theorem
a fibration.

So the ranks 
$\mathrm{rank} (H^q(X_s, \Omega_{X_s|k(s)}^p) = H^q(X, \Omega_{X|S}^p \tensor k(s)))$
which are in principle only upper
semicontinous (see Hartshorne's chapter on semicontinuity theorems) are constant for
varying $s \in S$.

Therefore again by the semicontinuity theorems, we have that $R^q f_* \Omega_{X|S}^p$
is a vector bundle on $S$ and we have isomorphisms

$$
H^a(X_s, \Omega_{X_s|k(s)}^b) = (R^a f_* \Omega_{X|S}^b) \tensor_{\Ohol_S} k(s)
$$

for all $s \in S$ and $a,b \geqslant 0$ ("Grauert's theorem").

Now it is $\Hdr^r(X/S) = \RR^r f_*(\Omega_{X|S}^\bullet)$ where at the left stands the
(algebraic) de Rham cohomology of $X/S$. The associated spectral sequence of
hypercohomology for $\RR f_*$ is the so called Hodge--de Rham sequence (or Frölicher sequence):
(here in a relative form for $X/S$):

$$
E_1^{pq} = ( R^q f_* \Omega_{X|S}^p ) \Rightarrow \RR^{p+q} f_* (\Omega_{X|S}^\bullet) = 
\Hdr^{p+q}(X/S)
$$

I want to prove that $E_r^{pq}$ degenerates at the level $r=1$, and I want to use only the facts
that the spectral sequence

$$
E_1^{pq}(k(s)) = (H^q(X_s, \Omega_{X_s|k(s)}))
$$

degenerates at $r=1$ for every $s \in S$ and
the assertions about the $R^a f_* \Omega_{X|S}^b$ from above.

So consider the differential
$\delta := d_1^{pq}:E_1^{pq} \to E_1^{p+1,q}$. It is a map
$\delta: R^q f_* \Omega_{X|S}^p \to R^q f_* \Omega_{X|S}^{p+1}$.

We tensor with $k(s)$  for $s \in S$ and get, that
$\delta \tensor k(s): H^q(X_s, \Omega_{X_s|s}^p) \to H^q(X_s, \Omega_{X_s|s}^{p+1})$
vanishes because of degeneration of $E_1^{pq}(k(s))$.

Considering $\delta$ as element of
$(R^q f_* \Omega^p_{X|S})^\vee \tensor (R^q f_* \Omega_{X|S}^{p+1})$ we get 
$\delta = 0$ therefore $E_2^{pq} = E_1^{pq}$.

Now we have to prove that $d^{pq}_r:E^{pq}_r \to E^{p+r,q-r+1}$ are all zero. Again I
want to show this by the same consideration for all $s \in S$, tensoring with $k(s)$.

By induction the $E_r^{pq}$ are equal to $E_1^{pq}$. So one takes
$d_r^{pq} \tensor k(s) = d_r^{pq}(k(s))$ (is this true? see my argument below) where 
$d_r^{pq}(k(s)): H^q(X_s,\Omega_{X_s|s}^p) \to H^{q-r+1}(X_s, \Omega_{X_s|s}^{p+r})$ 
is the map from the Hodge-de-Rham S-S for $X_s$ from level $r$ which we called
$E_r^{pq}(k(s))$ further above.

So again we have $d_r^{pq}\tensor k(s) = 0$ and with the argument from above $d_r^{pq} = 0$.

QUESTION 1: Is this argument valid up to now?

To justify $d_r^{pq} \tensor k(s) = d_r^{pq}(k(s))$ I argue as follows:

One starts with the zero level page $E_0^{pq}$ from Cech-cohomology
($U_i$ an affine cover of $X/S$ induced by $(X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^N_S)/S$).

$$
E_0^{pq} = \prod_{i_0 <\cdots < i_q} \Gamma(U_{i_0\cdots i_q}, \Omega_{X|S}^p)
$$

and writes the page $E_r^{pq}$ depending on it and on $d_0^{pq}$ as $E_r(E_0)$.

One has the diagram

\begin{CD}
E_r(E_0(k(s))) @>{d_r(k(s)) = 0}>>  E_r(E_0(k(s))) \\
@A=AA @A=AA \\
E_r(E_0 \tensor k(s)) @>{d_r(E_0 \tensor k(s))}>> E_r(E_0 \tensor k(s))\\
@A{\alpha_r}AA @A{\alpha_r}AA \\
E_r(E_0) \tensor k(s) @>{d_r \tensor k(s)}>> E_r(E_0) \tensor k(s)   
\end{CD}

In this diagram the $\alpha_r$ maps a "Zig-Zag" in $E_0$, which represents
an element of $E_r(E_0)$, tensored with $k(s)$, 
to a "Zig-Zag" in $E_0 \tensor k(s)$,
belonging to $E_r(E_0 \tensor k(s))$. (The side conditions on the Zig-Zag in $E_r(E_0)$
are retained upon tensoring with $k(s)$).

Additionally we have diagrams (with $Z_r = \ker d_r$)

\begin{CD}
E_r(E_0 \tensor k(s)) @<\supseteq<< Z_r(E_0 \tensor k(s))  @>>> E_{r+1}(E_0 \tensor k(s)) \\
@A\alpha_rAA @A\alpha'_rAA @A\alpha_{r+1}AA \\
E_r(E_0) \tensor k(s) @<{\supseteq}<<
 Z_r(E_0) \tensor k(s) @>>>  
 E_{r+1}(E_0) \tensor k(s) 
\end{CD}

Now $\alpha_1$ is an isomorphism, and so $d_1 \tensor k(s) = d_1(k(s)) = 0$. 
By the argument further above this gives $d_1 = 0$ and
$E_2 = E_1$. So $Z_1(E_0) = E_1(E_0)$ and in the last diagram above
all horizontal morphisms are isomorphisms and
$\alpha_1$ as much as $\alpha_1' = \alpha_1$ are isomorphisms too. So we conclude
$\alpha_2$ is an isomorphism. It follows $d_2 \tensor k(s) = d_2(k(s))$ and so we
proceed inductively.

QUESTION 2: Is this argument valid?

Assuming, that $E_r^{pq}$ really degenerates at $r=1$, we have a filtration
of the abutment $F^p \Hdr^r(X/S)$ with short exact sequences

$$
0 \to F^{p+1} \Hdr^r(X/S) \to F^p \Hdr^r(X/S) \to R^q f_* \Omega^p_{X|S} \to 0
$$

and therefore an isomorphism

$$
(*) \quad\quad \Hdr^r(X/S) = \bigoplus_{p+q = r} R^q f_* \Omega_{X|S}^p
$$

because for an exact sequence of vector bundles $0 \to F' \to F \to F'' \to 0$ on $S$
always $F = F' \oplus F''$ holds (consider $\mathrm{Ext}^1(F'', F') = 0$).

QUESTION 3: Is this argument valid, and do we really have the isomorphism $(*)$?

Comment: I don't have time to check carefully; your basic strategy seems fine initially. However the answer to Q3 is no, it won't split except in trivial cases.

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact you're assuming $S$ is affine. Then  Q3 is OK, but the splitting would be highly unnatural.

Comment: @Donu Arapura Thank you very much for taking the time to look at my proof (attempt)! I really had hoped that Q3 would be right, because I want to base an algorithm for explicitly calculating the Gauss-Manin connection in Macaulay2 on it.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, a reference for the degeneration is theoreme 5.5 of Deligne, *Theoreme de Lefschetz et criteres de degenerescence de suites spectrales*

Comment: Nitpick: Ehresmann's theorem only guarantees that there is a diffeomorphism between $X_s$ and $X_{s'}$, not a biholomorphism.

Comment: @Tony You are right, I was somehow thinking the usual result of Ehresmann would "strengthen itself" when one goes to the category of complex manifolds. But there is probably something more subtle involved here, which I am currently not aware of - does it have to do with "variation of complex structure in the family $f:X \to S$"?

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Yes, that is the issue here -- even in a topologically trivial family of complex manifolds, you'll need further assumptions to ensure that all of the fibers are isomorphic as complex manifolds.